# Is it possible to extract a list from a CMake INSTALL() command

Tags: cmake

I have an INSTALL(DIRECTORY) command which contains a FILES_MATCHING PATTERN and an EXCLUDE option. I would like to get a list of the files that are matched by this command and write it to a file. Is it possilbe to access the result of the INSTALL() command or do I have to reproduce it's behavior into a list manually?

My INSTALL() command looks like this:

```
INSTALL(
  DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/
  RELATIVE
  DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN "*_data.h" EXCLUDE)
```

Comment: Can't you GLOB the files first? See http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:file